# Intermediate product of CNO cycle

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, fusion, nucleosynthesis

`CNO` cycle of stellar nucleosynthesis involves several steps in which different isotopes of Carbon, Nitrogen, and Oxygen are transmuted into each other when hit by a free protons - this is a very simplified description.

\begin{align}
{}^{12}C + {}^{1}H &\to {}^{13}N + \gamma\\
{}^{13}N           &\to {}^{13}C + e\\
{}^{13}C + {}^{1}H &\to {}^{14}N + \gamma\\
{}^{14}N + {}^{1}H &\to {}^{15}O + \gamma\\
{}^{15}O           &\to {}^{15}N + e\\
{}^{15}N + {}^{1}H &\to {}^{12}C + {}^{4}He\\
\end{align}

My question is about the last step that produces an $\alpha$ particle. It looks like $^{16}O$ would be an intermediate product, which should be stable, similarly to two steps earlier which produce $^{15}O$ except $^{16}O$ is *more* stable so it wouldn't emit anything in the next step and break the cycle.
Why and how does $^{16}O$ emit $\alpha$?

#### edit

As pointed in the comment *sometimes*, especially at higher temperatures $^{16}O$ *does* remain stable and we get `CNO-II` cycle:

\begin{align}
{}^{14}N + {}^{1}H &\to {}^{15}O + \gamma\\
{}^{15}O           &\to {}^{15}N + e\\
{}^{15}N + {}^{1}H &\to {}^{16}O + \gamma\\
{}^{16}O + {}^{1}H &\to {}^{17}F + \gamma\\
{}^{17}F           &\to {}^{17}O + e\\
{}^{17}O + {}^{1}H &\to {}^{14}N + {}^{4}He\\
\end{align}

There are further modifications to this cycle at higher and higher temperatures, but we still call it `CNO` unfortunately, we could have really hot `FOFO` cycle instead of boring `CNO-IV`.

Anyway. Why does $^{16}O$ ever emit $\alpha$, and why is it *more* stable at *higher* temperatures? If anything I would expect protons with higher kinetic energy to create more unstable nuclei.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNO_cycle) says that a minor branch, CNO-II, *does* produce O-16 and a photon at that step, instead of the usual C-12 + He-4.

Comment: yes, good point. but it gives me more questions than answers. I will update my question. thanks

Comment: Oh, I totally agree! It seems backwards that the O-16 cycle is more stable at higher temperatures. Hopefully, one of the astrophysicists will give us a good answer.